# Which fonts can be correctly displayed in GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2, fonts

I just installed [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer), it's pretty cool. It also lets you add a background image and change the font.

However, the fonts always look bad (i.e. it's using a different font or what it thinks is a similar font to the one I've chosen). I tried a couple (including the Ubuntu font and such), but I'd like to avoid trial and error - What fonts are available within the grub and\or can I expand that somehow so it would look the way I configure it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a matter of personal preference and trial and error.

Comment: That depends on your definition of 'horrible' ;)

Comment: @Daniel I wasn't asking what are pretty fonts, I'm asking which ones should be available within the grub (I'll pick the one I like from there). Trial and error is what I'm trying to avoid here, as there should be a technical answer for this

Comment: @Ron In this context - distorted or different than the one I've configured to use

Comment: that's more 'technical' than horrible. So please use that in your question or your question might be closed because of  'primarily opinion-based' ;)

Comment: @Ron edited the question to emphasize what I'm asking

Comment: I guess you should edit your question and just write something like "Which fonts can be correctly displayed in GRUB", because your comments sound like some are either unreadable or replaced with a default font.

Comment: @ByteCommander yeah that sounds good, I changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although grub-customizer has a "font" option and shows the font in its preview, mine (5.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04) does not actually modify the font setting in `grub.cfg`.

I found a [blog post](https://www.gilesorr.com/blog/grub-graphical-and-fonts.html) that talks about using the `grub-mkfont` program to generate a font that Grub will use and putting these fonts under `/boot/grub/fonts/`. The post also says that some fonts don't look good after conversion but doesn't suggest any pattern or way of knowing what's good.

I ended up getting a theme from [Gnome-look](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/109/order/latest/) and using that (I used [Dark Squares](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1000129/)) and that included a more attractive font.

Comment: This is a useful comment but does not answer the question.

Comment: It's not the answer that I (or, presumably yuvi) would ideally want, but I believe that in the context of no other answer in 5 years since asking it is a valid answer per the guidance at https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer (and the asker appears to agree, having marked it "accepted"). It would be great if you wrote a more complete answer!